# Flora of Ice Age Europe

Tags: botany, trees, ecosystem

I'm trying to get a very in-depth idea of the ecosystem of Pleistocene Europe, somewhere around 40,000 years ago, and I can't seem to find what types of foliage (other than the obvious grasses and lichens) grew in that place and time. I'm particularly interested in the species of tree that were present; can anyone help?

Comment: 40,000 is not very long ago! it would be similar to today. tundra and deciduous similar species. check this from 50,000,000 years in america, it's still similar: http://geology.com/articles/green-river-fossils/plant-fossils.shtml

Comment: It strongly depends on how far North in Europe you mean. Scandinavia would be very different from France, which would be very different from Spain or Italy. But trees would not be very abundant North of the Alps I think.